# Using resource dictionary from a separate file gives me a designer error: Failed to set Source

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to add a resource dictionary to a page but I keep getting a designer error in my xaml. The app runs fine with no issue but the designer error bothers me.

Here's how I did it. Both works fin at run time. But it's saying Failed to set "Source". Any clues?

[image]
[image]

That also gives an error to all the static resource I used from the resource dictionary.

**Update:**

*This is another approach. Instead of directly adding it to the Page's resources, I added it to the Application.Resources still cant resolve the styles. I'm using VS2017 v15.4.4*

Steps to reproduce:

1. List item
2. Create a new UWP Application Project (App1)
3. Create a new UWP Class Library (ClassLibrary1)
4. In ClassLibrary1, add a new ResourceDictionary (Dictionary1.xaml).
5. In Dictionary1.xaml, add a Style, let's say a button style.

   `<Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="ButtonStyle1" x:Key="ButtonStyle1">
        <Setter Propeprty="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>`
6. In the ClassLibrary1, add a new BlankPage (BlankPage1)
7. In the BlankPage1, add a button and use ButtonStyle1
   `
8. In App1, merge the resource dictionary to App.Resources (inside App.xaml). 
   `<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///ClassLibrary1/Dictionary1.xaml" />
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>`
9. Make the BlankPage1 the start page, go to App.xaml.cs and and change MainPage to BlankPage1: 

     `if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
     {
       if (rootFrame.Content == null)
       {
         // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
         // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
         // parameter
         rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), e.Arguments);
       }
       // Ensure the current window is active
       Window.Current.Activate();
     }`
10. Run the application. It will run just fine. But the problem is in the designer where it cannot recognize the style from the resource dictionary.

Comment: Close and reopen designer or try restart visual studio

Comment: I do that all the time, I even restarted my PC :)

Comment: The `GasCheck.UWP` is namespace? The `Resources` is a folder which is created in the root directory of project?

Comment: The GasCheck.UWP is a folder. It just so happened that it's also the namespace that I'm using.

Comment: @LanceContreras You could try `/Resources/Styles.xaml`.

Comment: Hi @Bite, that's what I tried in my example. It gives me no error on runtime but I still get error in the designer.

Comment: Try to open Visual studio from dveloper command prompt by using command devenv.

Comment: No it didn't work for me. I'm adding a step to reproduce so you can easily reproduce it.

Comment: I submitted this to VS and they fixed the issue https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/154205/could-not-resolve-styles-from-a-resourcedictionary.html

Answer (score 3):

I followed your steps and found a typo and an issue.

The typo: In Style step (Perhaps only in the sample), There is typo in the word 'Proeprty':

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="ButtonStyle1" x:Key="ButtonStyle1">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style.Setters>
 </Style>
```

The issue in the way you are merging dictionary, it should be using the following syntax:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

After fixing both issues, Visual studio designer didn't complain about anything.

Did it fix the issue for you? If not then your steps to reproduce aren't complete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually submitted this to VS and they did a fix in 15.5.2. The steps I posted (except for the typo) can be reproduced in  the previous version.

Comment: You're right, I should have put <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionary> in my example, I corrected that. But unfortunately, it will still not work on versions prior to 15.5.2. Here's the bug I submitted to VS and they got it fixed. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/154205/could-not-resolve-styles-from-a-resourcedictionary.html